# Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я сделала схему предложения:

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, ссп

И лучших дней надежды и любовь в груди моей – все оживает вновь, и мысли далеко несутся, и полон ум желаний и страстей, и кровь кипит, и слезы из очей, как звуки, друг за другом льются.

И [ ], и [ ], и [ ], и [ ], и [ ].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Схема верная, ССП состоит из четырех предложений, связанных повторяющимся союзом И.